# Ubuntu 21.04 - unexpected shutdowns

Tags: grub2, nvidia, battery, 21.04, nvidia-geforce

My computer on **Ubuntu 21.04** shuts down unexpectedly, at random times. It shuts down while there is like **more than 3 hours left** until it gets drained completely, but once it gets to **50% and less of battery power**, it shows then that there is left only less than 45 minutes, and then shuts down. The computer won't boot if I pressed the power button, until I plug it in.
I've tried switching back and forth between the **NVIDIA driver version 390** and the one with **latest version (470)**. I have also changed some settings in the `/etc/default/grub` file, trying `quiet splash`, removing it, adding `nomodeset` and then finally removing it and adding `nouveau.modeset=0`, but none seemed to work.

When I execute the command `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`, I get the following output:

```
native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               HP
  model:                Primary
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Thu 28 Oct 2021 15:25:34 +01 (61 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              34.3392 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         34.3392 Wh
    energy-full-design:  34.3392 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             11.604 V
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1635431134  100.000 discharging
```

Comment: This could be a sign of a battery nearing its end of life. Could you [edit] your question to include the terminal output of `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`? What is the age of the battery?

Comment: @matigo Done. The computer is more than 2 years old, I've never been into bad habits regarding battery.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue of your operating system, it's a hardware issue. Ubuntu has no way of preventing your laptop from powering on.

Perhaps it is something that doesn't have to do with the battery at all.

Can you run diagnostics from the BIOS ?

Please report back.